# Creating An Inner Border

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I'm trying to create a button as below in HTML/CSS. What would be the best way of going about creating the white border that's slightly inside the actually edge of the button? I'm using ASP.net.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Button]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Yh/ Just a simple test, but you get the idea. make a inner-div with the border and an outer with the same background-color as the inner one.

Comment: I thought of that but I had hoped to just find a Button Style solution. Thanks

Comment: Notice that this may not work in IE. At least not 8 and older.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using *nesting inset box-shadows* you can create **[this](http://dabblet.com/gist/2658508)**:

[image]

with pure **one** html tag:

```
<button> view your receipts </button>
```

and some css:

```
button {
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    border-radius: 17px;
    background-color: #ffd28a;
    border: none;
    box-shadow:
            0 0 0  9px  #ffd28a inset,
            0 0 0 11px  #FFFFFF inset;
    color: red;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks like it could be a winner!

Comment: What I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Lot of fixed values here but just to show an example

```
<style type="text/css">
   .button { border: 3px solid orange; width: 300px; height: 50px; border-radius: 15px}
   .button a { background: orange; border: 1px solid #fff; line-height: 46px; border-radius:12px; color: red; text-align: center; margin:1px; display: block;}
</style>

<div class="button">
  <a href="#">Submit</a>
</div>
```